# How do I query one particular partition in Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a partitioned table, with partitions based on timestamp column, like this:

```
...
partition by date_trunc(update_date, month)
...
```

Now, how do I query partitions in this table?

Afaik, I can't use `_PARTITIONDATE` pseudo column, since this is not an ingestion-time partitioned table. Do I just filter my query using `date_trunc(update_date, month)`?

```
select * from my_project.my_dataset.information_schema.partitions
where table_name = 'partitioned_table'
```

Here I can get partition_ids, but I can't address them in my query either.

Comment: Yes.  Use `date_trunc(update_date, month)`, the expression used for partitioning.

Comment: Thank you! True, I just checked on the same table but without partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but whenever you want to to test if a partition is working: try typing out a `SELECT *` statement without a filter, and **don't run it** but check the estimated query size. Then try filtering on what you believe is the partition, also without running, and see if the estimated query size is reduced.

In this case try filtering on `date_trunc(update_date, month)` and see if it reduces the query size